# using $(this) jquery to change another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

So, I know how to change an attribute for the same element you hover over...

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function()
            {
              $(this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
             });
```

**question** Can I do the same thing but to affect another element only within the same 'click2play' div that was hovered?
maybe like?

```
  $(".click2play").mouseover(function()
            {
              $(this).(#someotherdiv).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
             });
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code targets a div, within the current .click2play element. I believe that's what you were asking for :)

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function() {
    $('div.class_name', this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU! YES! I think I wasn't communicating it as clearly as I could have. I'll try this out!

Comment: You're very welcome :) Your update to the posting definitely helped clarify things, and please note, you're not constrained to use the dot operator for class_name, you can also use div[attr="value"] or whatever suits your needs! :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, could you send me a link to where I can learn about that?

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ The documentation is sparse, but all in all, if you have any jquery / dom element, you can pass it in to the typical selector syntax as a second argument and it will search all elements, within the second argument. For example, $('div', $('p:first')).text('Testing'); would change the div text, inside of the first paragraph element, to Testing

Answer (score 1):

not very clear from the ques what you wanna do so ill ans for all the options i can guess of
1.if you wanna hide all the elements of class `.click2Play` then use

```
$('.click2Play').hover(function(){$('.click2play').hide()});
```

2.if you want to just hide the current element of all the elements having this class use

```
$('.click2Play').hover(function(){$(this).hide()});
```

3.if you wanna generalize it then you can use.selector property of the jquery object so that you would be able to use it like

```
$('.click2Play').hover(function(){$($(this).selector).hide()});
```

so now if you will change the class name from .click2Play to some other class it will work nicely and will hide all the elements of that class.
4. if you want to hide some element inside that of current element then

```
$('.click2Play').hover(function(){$(this).children('selector_of_child').hide()});
```

5.if all the elements of this class have an element inside them having some other class and you wanna hide them all then simple use each like this

```
$('.click2Play').hover(function(){$('.click2play').each(function(){$(this).children("selector_Of_Child").hide()})});
```

Comment: ooh sry just change "hover" to "mouseover"

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

But maybe it isn't what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this :):

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
});
```

or better

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change some other div? Why would you need `$(this)`?

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function(){
    $("#someotherdiv").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a single css attribute you can do:

```
$(".click2play").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

I hope it helps
(consider to see this link: http://marakana.com/bookshelf/jquery_tutorial/css_styling.html )

Answer (score 0):

I believe most of the answers didn't payed attention to the question, which asks about removing a class. Here is the answer to both questions:

```
$('.click2play').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('click2play'); // This line removes the current object's class click2play
  $('jQUerySelector').removeClass('click2play'); // This will remove another element's class click2play
});
```